# POST method can't be used error

Tags: java, servlets, post, jakarta-ee, glassfish

So i have this simple setup, a simple HTML page with a simple input form and a servlet that i want to get the parameters from the input of user, but it's giving me an error that post method is not allowed to use in this case. Here is the code:

HTML page:

```
  <html>
<body>
<h1>SIMPLE HTML</h1>

<form action="user/search" method="post">
    <p>
        Table name : <input type="text" name="table" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Date : <input type="text" name="date" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

SERVLET that should return the parameters:

```
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/user")
public class Input {

    @POST
    @Path("/search")
    public Response introMessage(
        @FormParam("table") String name,
        @FormParam("date") String date
    )
    {
        return Response.status(200).entity(name + "    " + date).build();
    }

}
```

WEB.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

Deploying the .war to GlassFish server.

Comment: Can you give us exact exception that you receive?

Answer (score 0):

I made it, the problem was that i didn't type the right path in browser